# "No space left on device" when copying files to barely used 5TB NTFS external drive on Xubuntu

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a 5TB drive attached via USB3 to machine running Xubuntu.  The drive is formatted with a single NTFS partition.  I'm trying to copy about 400GB of files to it, and it has way more than enough space as per the entry for /dev/sdb2 below:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G   18M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       410G  319G   70G  83% /
tmpfs            32G  152K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           6.3G   36K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb2       4.6T  275G  4.3T   6% /media/josh/5TB-2016-05-08
```

When searching for the source of this error a common problem raised was not having enough inodes, but that doesn't appear to be the problem here:

```
df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             7.9M   570  7.9M    1% /dev
tmpfs            7.9M   867  7.9M    1% /run
/dev/sda2         26M  679K   26M    3% /
tmpfs            7.9M     7  7.9M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            7.9M     5  7.9M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            7.9M    16  7.9M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            7.9M    22  7.9M    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb2        4.3G  489K  4.3G    1% /media/josh/5TB-2016-05-08
```

I also ran across [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/357367/xfs-no-space-left-on-device-but-i-have-850gb-available).  Even though the drive isn't really very close to have a TB written to it, I tried unmounting and remounting it with the inode64 option, but not joy (yeah, its different filesystem).

It doesn't matter if I copy all of the files at once, or do it directory by directory.  Ultimately I start getting "No space left on device" errors before all of the files are copied.

Comment: How are you copying ?

Comment: cp -a <source dir> <dest dir>

Answer (score 1):

When I connected the drive to a Windows box, I found the parent directory of the destination directory had compression turned on.  Turning compression off for that folder and reconnecting to the Xubuntu box allowed the entire set of files to be copied successfully.  Of course this means that more space was used than when previous attempts had failed near the end of the copy with a "No space left on device" error.  Seems like there was some failure related to compression that was not clearly communicated.