# Deleted files from external SSD but it will not let me write new files to SSD - Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, ssd, memory-usage

Ubuntu version 18.04.5 LTS

My external SSD filled up in memory so in an attempt to clear up space on my drive I decided to delete many files permanently. I deleted about 1.4TB and after running `df -h`. It seemed to have worked just fine, because I can see free space on the disk (see below)

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                    1.9T  530G  1.4T  29% /media/me/EXT_SSD
```

However, whenever I try to write new things into the disk it does not let me do it, and it keeps saying the disk is full. Have anyone encountered this issue and know of any solutions?

I tried rebooting the machine, I tried unmounting and remounting the SSD. It is formatted NTFS. I emptied the trash directory as well. I have also checked the number of Inodes and it seems fine as well.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995702/no-space-left-on-device-when-copying-files-to-barely-used-5tb-ntfs-external-dr?rq=1 maybe?

Comment: I just attempted this and it did not work

Comment: Have you made sure the trash is emptied as well.

Comment: Yes, the trash has been emptied as well!